# Converting an array of objects into an array node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I currently have an array of objects which is the following.

```
[
  { desc: '1', qty: '2', amt: '1', index: 0 },
  { desc: '1', qty: '2', amt: '1', index: 1 }
]
```

I need to turn this array of objects to something like that

```
[
     ['1','2','1',0 ],
     ['1','2','1',1]
]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The desired output has no valid syntax. Instead of `{}` you can have `[]` for each elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order of the properties in the object is guaranteed, you can use create a new array with `Array.map()`, and use `Object.values()` as the callback:

```js
const arr = [
  { desc: '1', qty: '2', amt: '1', index: 0 },
  { desc: '1', qty: '2', amt: '1', index: 1 }
]

const result = arr.map(Object.values)

console.log(result)
```

If the order of the properties in the objects might change, use `Array.map()`, and then call `Array.map()` again to extract the properties that you want in the the order you specify:

```js
const arr = [
  { desc: '1', qty: '2', amt: '1', index: 0 },
  { desc: '1', qty: '2', amt: '1', index: 1 }
]

const order = ['desc', 'qty', 'amt']; // 'index' removed

const result = arr.map(o => order.map(k => o[k]))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: i want to ask you if i want to ignore one element like i dont want "index" in my new array is it possible?

Comment: If you use the 2nd method (the `order` array), you can decide which properties to include. See updated example.

Comment: thank you!! can i ask you one more question? sorry for bothering

Comment: Sure. As long as it's related to the current question/answer.

Comment: yes it is, i need to add a separate value to my new array (the one we got after the mapping). how can i add that value i have it saved as a let

Comment: You can map again, but an easier solution would be to include it while you extract the values from the objects: `[...order.map(k => o[k]), additionalValue]` - spread the the array of values from the object into a new array, and add whatever value you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221784/discussion-between-jayzee-and-ori-drori).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

> The `Object.values()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a `for...in` loop. (The only difference is that a `for...in` loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well.)

Try as the following:

```js
const data = [
  { desc: '1', qty: '2', amt: '1', index: 0 },
  { desc: '1', qty: '2', amt: '1', index: 1 }
]

const result = data.map(e => Object.values(e))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const data = [
  { desc: '1', qty: '2', amt: '1', index: 0 },
  { desc: '1', qty: '2', amt: '1', index: 1 }
];

var arr = [];

data.map(function(obj) {
   arr.push(Object.values(obj))
});

console.log(arr) // value gets stored in arr object
```